# How can I prevent the error "the class name or namespace probably has a typo" in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, class, namespaces, yaml

I get the following error message...

> The autoloader expected class "App\DataTables\UsersDataTable" to be
>   defined in file
>   "/Users/work/project/vendor/composer/../../src/DataTables/UsersDataTable.php".
>   The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo in
>   /Users/work/project/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource
>   "/Users/work/project/config/services.yaml").

But my *scr/DataTables/UsersDataTable.php* has a correct namespace and class:

```
namespace App\DataTables\UsersDataTable;

use DataTables\DataTableHandlerInterface;
use DataTables\DataTableQuery;
use DataTables\DataTableResults;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

class UsersDataTable implements DataTableHandlerInterface
{....
```

In *config/service.yaml* I name it like this...

```
datatable.users:
   class: App\DataTables\UsersDataTable
   tags: [{ name: datatable, id: users }]
   arguments: [ '@doctrine' ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there!
The namespace statement indicates "I am under this **directory**" (well, namespace)
The `use` statement indicates: load this **class** (= a file)

```
namespace App\DataTables;

use DataTables\DataTableHandlerInterface;
// [...]

class UsersDataTable extends DataTableHandlerInterface
{
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The error message is gone. There is now another error message `InvalidArgumentException Cannot determine controller argument for "App\Controller\DataTableController::usersAction()": the $request argument is type-hinted with the non-existent class or interface: "App\Controller\Request". Did you forget to add a use statement?`  But this has nothing to do with this problem right?

Comment: `Did you forget to add a use statement?` => Yes you do. Do you use a modern IDE like PHPstorm? Modern IDE software include automatically classes

Comment: Yes, I am using Atom Editor

Comment: I don't use Atom but try to ctrl + Enter or Ctrl + space on the Request class to automaticcaly include the use statement.

Comment: Hm, I do not know exactly how to do that and where exactly

Comment: WHen you have 10 minutes to loose, try PhpStrom, it supports very well symfony and PHP. (I am not related to PhpStorm, just statisfied by their product). It's free for students